# how to show required proptype error on build time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I am using `prop-types` library in my demo project .I added a required field .it is showing correct error on development on console .But when I create a build I didn't see any error ?

How to show error on build

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-surf-rb3n6?file=/src/App.js

```
Test.propTypes = {
  str: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
Test.defaultProps = {};
```

`str` is required but. when I create a build I am not passing this value.Expected output is it show error when i run my build .it is not showing any error

Comment: React proptypes are runtime-only checks, in non-production builds.

Comment: any way to show error ?

Comment: In development builds the errors are shown in the console by default. Are you experiencing something other than this in development builds?